# Is this persistent termite damage or could it be caused by wasps?

Tags: pest-control, damage, pest, termite

We've had some visible damage through a ceiling joint, and the attached picture is what it looks like in the attic. We had a pest control company come out and treat for termites with termidor by installing bait stations around the perimeter of the house. It seems like this damage has persisted though. We also had a wasp infestation very close to this part of the house where they were nesting inside the wood. Is there a chance this damage was caused by those wasps, or am I still fighting termites? The termites were treated last November, so the bait stations have been installed for close to a year.

[image]

Let me know if you have any suggestions on next steps.

Comment: Since you're asking about what caused the damage, I assume you haven't seen any critters in the neighborhood. How do you know that this damage doesn't predate the termite treatment?

Comment: Nope, I haven't seen any critters. I dug around in it a bit hoping I would see something, but I didn't see anything with my untrained eye. After treating for termites last November, we waited about a month and then repaired the interior damage where there were some holes in the drywall and repainted. Some new interior damage became visible this month. I don't know for sure that this picture isn't of the old damage. At that time, I didn't really dig through the insulation to clean things up.

Comment: Live critters is the necessary condition that I would look to satisfy before planning the funeral. I still have some of that fipronil stuff out in the garage from treating carpenter ants somewhat recently, where in your position I would use the stuff.

Comment: All I see is a bunch of white fluff.  Is that the "damage" you're asking about?

Comment: Why were there holes in drywall from termites? There was a roof leak? Or otherwise? If wasps can get in, so can water. If the termites were so bad the drywall started falling off, then you need to knock the house down. Stop calling pest control for what is a guy's job that actually does something for a living.

Comment: Looks like water damage on that plywood. That's the roofer or siding guy's fault. Not bugs.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above. You had water damage, so you tore open a wall, and it looks like every other open wall ever, which if it's your first time you go *OMG*. And probably *Look, there's bugs; call the guy.*

When really all you had to do was fix the leak and then the drywall. And when you see wasps flying at, and then into your house, you need to get on a ladder with some caulk.

Comment: "After treating for termites last November, we waited about a month and then repaired the interior damage where there were some holes in the drywall and repainted. Some new interior damage became visible this month" **Fix the leak!**

Comment: Correct answer. But if I were looking for something to blame, I'd say mice.

Comment: We'll definitely look into the leak. When we initially noticed the damage, our moisture meter wasn't picking up any moisture. When we went into the attic, we noticed the debri in the pic and thought it looked like termite droppings. Maybe instead it's just debri being brought into the attic through the leak.

Comment: @MikeBockus - I've never used a moisture meter, ever. **If there's a brown spot in the ceiling, there's a leak** or you have rats. I find dead bugs and mice in the walls all the time. "*Live* critters is the necessary condition that I would look to satisfy before planning the funeral." *Finish the demo.* If you had cut holes from below, all that crap just falls away and you wouldn't have a chance to go *eww*. And you can now find the leak, and you don't patch drywall until you fix it.